# Android Studio - onTouchEvent - Wanting a new screen to appear after 7 ACTION_DOWN events

Tags: java, android-studio, touch-event

As title suggests, I want a new screen to appear after 7 ACTION_DOWN events are logged by my OnTouchEvent.

Can get it working for a single ACTION_DOWN, but not sure how to make it pop after 7 of them.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        int count = event.getPointerCount();

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            count++;
        }

        if (count == 7) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, UsersList.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to log `count` at each call, just before the second `if`

Answer (score 0):

That's a variable scope problem you have there. That variable `count` only lives for the duration of the `onTouchEvent` method. You'll have to put that variable into a bigger scope, like your class for exemple.

Also, I suggest you to look at the [getPointerCount](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#getPointerCount()) method documentation. This might not be want you think...